# Error in testing phpUnit route: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm a novice developer and I'm trying to get phpUnit set up and a rudimentary testing suite set up in an existing app that I did not develop.  I'm going through the laravel docs and trying to get some basic tests run.  When I try to run the following:

```
$response = $this->action('GET', 'AlertsController@bannerAlerts');
```

I get the following exception:

```
AlertsControllerTest::testIndexRoute
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

The method I'm calling is:

```
public function count() {
    $statusIds = DB::table('alert_status')->where('user_id', $this->crmUser->id)->where('is_new', 0)->lists('alert_id');
    $count = DB::table('alerts')->WhereNotIn('id', $statusIds)->count();
    return Response::json($count);
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?  To my knowledge, I'm not trying to get properties of anything.  I'm just trying to call the route.

The test method throwing the error is:

```
   public function testIndexRoute() { 
       $this->crmUser = new stdClass();  
       $this->crmUser->id = new stdClass(); 
       $this->crmUser->id = 1; 
       $response = $this->action('GET','AlertsController@bannerAlerts');           
       $count = $response->original; $this->assertResponseOk(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the very limited info in the post, I'm guessing the issue is `$this->crmUser->id`.  Before you call the DB in the count method try to do a `var_dump` of the `crmUser`.

I'm guessing your unit test didn't setup a crmUser for the instance of the class which the `count()` method being tested belongs to.

```
public function count() {
      var_dump($this->crmUser);
      $statusIds = DB::table('alert_status')->where('user_id', $this->crmUser->id)->where('is_new', 0)->lists('alert_id');
      $count = DB::table('alerts')->WhereNotIn('id', $statusIds)->count();
      return Response::json($count);
 }
```

It would help a great deal if you posted the text of your phpunit test method.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error though...
public function testIndexRoute()
    {

        $this->crmUser = new stdClass();
        $this->crmUser->id = new stdClass();
        $this->crmUser->id = 1;

        $response = $this->action('GET', 'AlertsController@bannerAlerts');

        $count = $response->original;

        $this->assertResponseOk();

    }

Comment: @brianfr82 I added your test method to the OP.  Your problem is you're now adding `$this->crmUser` inside the test method add it to the `AlertsControllerTest`, not the class being tested.  You need to inject the user into the tested class, the instance of the `AlertsController`

Comment: I follow what you're saying but I'm not sure how to actually do it in php.  Could you explain in a bit more depth?  Sorry, I'm woefully inexperienced and I'm having a lot thrown at me.

Comment: What does the class `AlertsControllerTest` extend?

Comment: A BaseController class.  Its constructor sets up the crmUser

Comment: I'm guessing calling an action on an arbitrary controller creates intiallizes the instance of the crmUser it in the constructor.   How does one specify a user normally when calling the API?  Is it a get parameter, in a header, etc...?

Comment: Typically, when I unit test a method, I manually instatiate the class  then explicitly set the state of the instance prior to calling the specific method directly--not using some type of controller routing.  That way you're testing the method alone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try going that route.  Per your last question... I'm not really sure.  The crmUser is set up at login and I'm still very new to web development so I'm not sure where the user is specified.  Perhaps as a session parameter? I'm not sure.  Thanks for your help and patience.